Help journalists implement Visual Hierarchy using their existing building blocks
I have to convince some web editors (who have a strong journalistic background) that visual hierarchy is essential when building a web page. And I have to teach them what this means using the elements (images, some info boxes, several text elements, accordions, etc.) they have at hand.
My main problem is: The site uses a single column layout (mobile first approach) and they tend to put strong visual elements immediately beneath each other, like so: A big image, two rows of info boxes containing big icons and finally a diagram. Even on a large screen, all the users see are those visually dominant elements. And on a mobile device they have to scroll five or six screens down to find the beginning of the text and the main content. (Update: See some mockups below)
I'm concerned there are two problems with what they do:

Having only strong visual elements, the reader has no chance to quickly scan the page and doesn't know what to do.
Only seeing visual elements the reader may get the impression that this is some kind of lightweight overview page and leave the page as they don't realize there's a lot of deeply researched text content further below the page.

My main questions are:

Is visual hierarchy the correct term for what I want them to understand?
How can I convince them this is not some question of taste (that's what they're saying to me), but has some well researched scientific background? For now, I try to show them some eye tracking screenshots where they can see how focus goes from one strong element to the next, but perhaps there are other ideas to communicate the idea?

Some background: I'm an online marketer, working with a client (a non-profit organization) whose web editors are mostly building pages with long form content. Previously, their pages were rather simple: A big headline, some teaser text, a big image and then lots of paragraphs, sometimes with small headlines and other images. Now they want to offer more short-form content at the top of each page, but also keeping the good text content further down. While this is a good idea in principle, I'm concerned the way they implement it makes their pages worse.
Update:
Below you'll find mockups of two primary solutions we're discussing. These mockups are simulating the desktop view (imagine lots of unused space to the left and the right of the shown content). On smartphones the icon boxes are stacked to a single column, stretching the area without body text even more.
A bad example. Why do I consider this bad? The visitor has no help to skim the page and gets the impression he'll only find images and some short boxes of information on this page. (Please note that on typical desktop browser sizes the "fold" is somewhere near the second row of the icon boxes.)

full size image
A better example. Why do I consider it better? The variation between strong visual content and body text helps the user to skim the page. And it conveys the notion that further down he'll find lots of text content.

full size image

A visual example of your well-explained statement may help finding an answer.

To your update: Yes, fully agreeing with you. Those icon boxes make the impression to me of being "read more here" links or "look at pictures" etc. Maybe they can be provided as a row of icon buttons only and on click/tap the sub-items are presented. --- However, if the items are not links to external places, but they are like a table of contents and jump further down the page, this would be a good menu approach, showing everything at a glance.

Yes, visual hierachy is the right term, see https://nngroup.com/articles/principles-visual-design, but also check "user journey" for a broader scale, see for example: https://uxplanet.org/user-journey-map-and-user-flow-what-is-the-difference-between-them-and-when-to-use-each-0e9998c039d0

You can also take a look at "cards" as a UI term.

UX-Design Basics
Top-Level Elements
One key element is the link that gets you to the page you describe:

If it is something descriptive like "See our research paper on XY" then it is relatively clear that text will be there somewhere and the user is inclined to spend time on reading that paper anyways.

If the link says something like "Product XY" then it might be not clear that there is a lot of text coming, the user probably scans the first one or two swipes down and then leaves again if he did not find what he wanted to know.


If the initial images contain (textual) information that indicate to the user that there is more information coming then maybe the user's focus and attention can be guided downwards the page.
A bad example (you gave that mainly already) would be:

A meaningless cover image (some stock photo of two coworkers doing something "productive")
a large font title repeating the text from the link where you got from
followed by an image of a product or closeup of something of the content but without further context
followed by a diagram which shows some properties that are nice to know but also without content hard to get and the font on it is so small that you need to enlarge it to read it as if using a magnifying glass.
Then following blocks and blocks of unstructured text.

Golden Rule
There is one golden rule in User Experience Design, that is
"Don't make me think"

Sometimes aliased as "KISS" - Keep It Simple Stupid.
If the user has to waste a thought or two to determine if he is right at that page, the page has already lost him, resulting in a high churn rate overall.
A good analogy is thinking in terms of energy invested before reaching something of value. If a user has to swipe a lot, he has to invest energy by moving the thumb, which will make her/him realize if the balance is not right and will decide if it is worth it or not.
This really is not about taste
Your gut feeling is right. There are best practices and studies behind it. Any book about UX-Design or some styleguides will provide you plenty of links on that topic. Maybe these get you started:

Norman Group on UX-Design Principle Studies - This covers a wide variety of topics on Mobile UX-Design. The articles are short, but give enough hints to continue researching further.
This outlines some testing methods to get hard data on churn rates - Automated Logging could be worth a look for you.
This article is more focused on the research aspects and more verbose, but interesting to dig deeper on methods to obtain data.

Suggestion

Design: Consider maybe providing a more "paged" design. A small frame picture which enlarges when tapped upon. Making space for introductory text around the picture on the first screen. If the user suspects it, maybe make that a short page (backed by data better than just by feeling). Maybe even paginated, so the user can also swipe left and right to quickly glance over the contents. Then he can decide which page to continue by hitting a "Read more" button (although it is commonly used "Read more" is a bad practice. Some text with more substance to it would be more beneficial).

Get real data: Instead of eye tracking examples you might turn to churn rate analysis with some random people on the concrete pages to show them the "hard truth". Depends which tools and time you have at hand.



Thanks for the detailed answer, but it somewhat misses my problems. I have no control over the links visitors come from as most come from outside (social, search, links). And I'm in no position to change the design. I can just help using the given elements correctly. As it's a non-profit org, they don't have much money for detailed tests. Your answer as well as the comment from @Danielillo show me I have to give some better briefing, though.

Okay, I understood it as you need some basics to evaluate the design and push your confidence in your opinion about the design and you are able to make improvement suggestions. Hopefully you can cherry pick something from my post or some other answers will help you more.

Yes, your answer was helpful. My main focus is how to convince them that it's not simply a matter of taste, but about some good UX reasons.

Well, you either can cite UX rules and guidelines from researches done prior (therefore you need to search those which fit best in your situation), or you gather your own data by conducting usability tests. Those two ways would be the scientific approach at least. If you mean "convince" in terms of interpersonal persuasion skills, that is a whole other question. One simple guideline: "If they do not want to - leave it be". Offer them improvements, but you cannot force anyone.

"Is visual hierarchy the correct term for what I want them to understand?" - only to a degree.
By your description, your workmates not only do not understand visual hierarchy but they also do not understand what user interface is.
A newspaper or magazine is persuasive content on the first place, not UI. Its main purpose is to persuade/ trigger emotions/ embed biases/ shape public opinion, etc. Sure, when that content is online, it also involves UI, but UI is of secondary importance here.
Now thing of an ATM/ steering wheel controls/ traffic lights/ washing machine settings and... a commercial web site. All those are user interfaces. The user interacts with what is in front of them and that interaction brings some output for them. The purpose is that output - get cash from the ATM, move the car from point A to point B/ know when to cross the crossroads/ get your laundry done/ purchase an item online. Persuasion/ emotions/ biases/ etc, may very well be involved in the process, but they are not the immediate goal.
I suspect this is the differentiation your workmates are not making. (Most of the so called "UX designers" do not make it, either. A whole different topic.)

"How can I convince them..." - do you have any decision-making power over them? If not, it is not your job and not your authority to convince them. You should be trying to convince whoever in the company has that decision-making power. In the time-being you can only educate them. But even if educated, they may still insist to have things their way, because otherwise, they'd be admitting that they are less competent than how they appeared to be when they were getting hired.
If you do have decision-making power over them, you can ask them to attend usability tests on your specific UI and see first-hand how users perceive UIs. Then you can ask them to substantiate their future decisions of disregarding visual hierarchy with usability tests.

Thank you, lots of interesting hints. Regarding "convince": Yes, "educate" would've been the better word. As it's an NGO, the hierarchy of decision makers isn't as clear as it's in companies.

@z80crew - hierarchy is always clear, everywhere in nature :) Whoever has the power to sanction you, if you are not doing what asked, the way asked, they are the real decision-maker :)
